# How many ways are there have a n-digit number using digits 1 up to n? Order is irrelevant.

Tags: combinatorics

For example, if *n* = 3, there are 10 possibilities:
111, 222, 333, 112, 113, 221, 223, 331, 332, 123

For *n* = 4, there are 35 possibilities;
For *n* = 5, there are 126 possibilities;
For *n* = 6, there are 446 possibilities;
For *n* = 7, there are 1569 possibilities;

I have found a way to calculate it, but it seems that I am going the long way. It goes like this:
For *n* = 5, find all the possible partitions, where each element is the length of equal digit sets in the number:
(5) -> 11111, 22222...
(4,1) -> 11112, 11113...
(3,2) -> 11122, 11133...
(3,1,1) -> 11123, 11124...
(2,2,1) -> 11223, 11224...
(2,1,1,1) -> 11234, 11235...
(1,1,1,1,1) -> 12345
Then, to calculate the number of combinations *m* of a given partition with *k* elements, I have found the following pattern:
$$
m = {n!\over(n-k)!\prod_{i=1}^n s_i!}
$$
Where $s_i$ is the number of sets of length *i*. Back to the example where *n* = 5, the number of combinations for each partition is:
(5) -> 1 set = 5!/(5-1)! = 5!/4! = 5
(4,1) -> 2 sets = 5!/(5-2)! = 5!/3! = 20
(3,2) -> 2 sets = 5!/(5-2)! = 5!/3! = 20
(3,1,1) -> 3 sets, 2 sets of length 1 = 5!/(5-3)!/2! = 5!/2!/2! = 30
(2,2,1) -> 3 sets, 2 sets of length 2 = 5!/(5-3)!/2! = 5!/2!/2! = 30
(2,1,1,1) -> 4 sets, 3 sets of length 1 = 5!/(5-4)!/3! = 5!/3! = 20
(1,1,1,1,1) -> 5 sets, 5 sets of length 1 = 5!/(5-5)!/5! = 5!/5! = 1
Finally, sum it all: 5+20+20+30+30+20+1 = **126**

Is there an easier and more scalable way?

Comment: For $n=3$ what about $121$ or $122$ or many of the other ones you didn't write out...  You say "order is irrelevant" so these are considered the same outcome as $112$ and $221$ in your list?  Why bother describing these as "n-digit numbers" then?  Why didn't you write them all in strictly increasing order to make it cleaner?

Comment: Let $x_1$ be the number of $1$'s used in the number.  Let $x_2$ be number of $2$'s, etc... then you have the system $\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=n\\0\leq x_i\end{cases}$.  Apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to conclude that there are $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ arrangements.

Comment: @JMoravitz. He didn’t list the numbers you mentioned because he stipulated order is irrelevant. -we are talking about combinations, not permutations. Thus 112 is the same as 121, so he didn’t list 121.

Comment: @John you didn't read my entire comment.  My complaint was that he presented the information in a non- standard way and the objects he is trying to count are much better presented as strings of digits where the digits occur in strictly increasing order as this makes it easy to see if any were missed.  Regardless, my second comment gives enough information to solve this very standard and routine counting problem.

Comment: Checking with a Python program, I think it should be $462$ for $n = 6$ and $1716$ for $n=7$.